# PHP - GMP and floating point numbers?

Tags: php, gmp

The following code outputs 0, which isn't correct:

```
$r = gmp_pow(gmp_init('-1.7976931348623157'), 308);
echo gmp_strval($r);
```

I was under the impression that the GMP library was capable of handling floating point numbers, or have I made a mistake in the code?

Comment: Wow, I could have swear I've used floats with GMP too. :O

Comment: this may be a limitation of PHP's gmp wrapper, rather than an actual GMP limitation.. im just guessing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> GMP library was capable of handling floating point numbers,

It's not. You can test that with:

```
echo gmp_strval(gmp_init('18')); // 18
echo gmp_strval(gmp_init('1.8')); // 0
```

---

Now, what you *could* do is use [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) instead:

```
$num = bcpow('-1.7976931348623157', '308');
echo $num;
echo floatval($num); // for a "prettier" format
```

Comment: This is what I found too. I checked the library's wiki page and it said otherwise. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library) This is weird.

Comment: @Matty It seems like PHP uses GMP for arbitrary length integers only: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Yup, you're right. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php also says this. I glossed right over that because the PHP extension is supposed to be a wrapper for the GMP library. I guess it's an incomplete one.